# How to pass Date parameter to annotation and then validate it in junit 5 extension?

Tags: java, junit, interface, annotations, junit5

So I have extension to skip the tests according some conditions. One of this condition should be date, for example target date for fix,and before this day, we will skip the test:

```
public class KnownIssueExtension implements ExecutionCondition {
@Override
public ConditionEvaluationResult evaluateExecutionCondition(ExtensionContext context) {

    Date now = new Date();

    final Optional<Method> testMethod = context.getTestMethod();
    if (testMethod.isPresent()
            && testMethod.get().isAnnotationPresent(KnownIssue.class) && now.before(testMethod.get().getAnnotation(KnownIssue.class).date())) {
        return disabled(testMethod.get().getAnnotation(KnownIssue.class).description());
    }
    return enabled("");
}
```

So I want to get current date into annotation like parameter, but i can't assign any default value or something like this.

**Now it looks like:**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface KnownIssue {
    String description()
            default "Please set the reason for the expected failure like: @KnownIssue(description = \"TPSVC-12345\")";

Date date()
            default "I DONT KNOW WHAT SHOULD BE HERE, I have tried new Date(), but it's not working"

}
```

Comment: How specific to be a date do you need?  Annotation values need to be constant expressions, so you'll struggle with a `Date` object.  You could take a `String` and request people fill it out in ISO8601 or similar.  Or have multiple `int` (or other, `enum` for `month`, etc.) members for `year()`, `month()`, etc.  Or even another annotation for `@Date` which does this, so you can reuse it in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your annotation as follows.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Documented
public @interface KnownIssue {

    String since();

    String description() default "";
}
```

Document that the `since` attribute is required to conform to the ISO standard date format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Then parse the `String` into a `java.util.Date` (e.g., via `java.text.DateFormat.parse(String)`) or into a `java.time.LocalDate` (e.g., via `java.time.LocalDate.parse(CharSequence)`).